# recover lvm formatted partition

Tags: centos, partition, hard-disk, lvm, data-recovery

I had 2 old drives having LVM installed showing as 1 drive. They were attached by the datacenter to the new server to migrate data but they weren't able to be mounted I tried everything possible until I accidentally formatted them

```
mkfs.ext3 /dev/sdd1
```

Is there a way to recover the data please advise.

Comment: No, ext3 usually writes its superblock well within the location of the LVM head. If the other drive has an uncorrupted LVM head you might use `dd` to copy over the first meg from that and then do a `pvck` and see if it comes back. That's kind of a hail mary though.

Comment: @Bratchley thanks for your reply can you advise me with commands that help me do the trick for `dd` and for `pvck` thank you